# How can I animate by passing arguments in funcAnimation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have to make a time-varying geographic plot.

```
def animate(tindex, ax):
    summasel = summaout.isel(time = tindex)['pptrate'].drop('time').to_dataframe()
    summasel['hru_id2'] = summasel.index
    polydat2 = pd.merge(polydat, summasel)
    return (polydat2.plot(ax = ax, column = 'pptrate', cmap='viridis_r', scheme='quantiles'),)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=40, fargs=(ax,), blit=True)
HTML(a.to_html5_video())
```

Basically, `tindex` is a number with a range, say `1:10`. For every `tindex`, `polydat2.plot` plots a shapefile with variable `pptrate`.

How can I pass this range to animate? Probably my syntax is all wrong.

## ERROR

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py in _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
     37         except (AttributeError, TypeError, ValueError):
     38             raise ValueError("Invalid file object: "
---> 39                              "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
     40     if fd < 0:
     41         raise ValueError("Invalid file descriptor: {}".format(fd))

ValueError: Invalid file object: <_io.BufferedReader name=58>
```

[This is what the plot looks like for one time instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lODFy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lODFy.png)

## print(polydat2.head(2))

```
   OBJECTID    POI_ID PROD_UNIT  hru_elev   hru_id2    Y_Centroid  \
0         1  23336004       17a    1829.0  17000001  2.213807e+06   
1         2  23198872       17a    1902.0  17000002  2.214667e+06   

     X_Centroid    Basin_Area  seg_hru_id    Elev_Avg  Lon_Centro  Lat_Centro  \
0 -1.665466e+06  1.202901e+08    17001133  1890.24521  -116.20479    41.33139   
1 -1.555784e+06  1.248356e+08    17000804  1959.87124  -114.91219    41.53916   

                                            geometry   pptrate  
0  POLYGON ((-116.1746602138565 41.40417605744236...  0.000005  
1  (POLYGON ((-114.6447601321217 41.5900497438992...  0.000001
```

## EDIT

I tried saving the plot instead of showing it. And used a codec directly (REF ISSUE)

```
a.save('./movie.mp4', writer='ffmpeg', codec='rawvideo')
```

I *NO LONGER* have the errors above. But I am still getting an empty plot.

Comment: The error suggests you have a problem saving the animation, not producing it. The code looks in principle ok, but since it is not runnable, one cannot test it. I would suggest you first check if the animation is correctly running by showing it on screen instead of saving it and in case you cannot solve the problem produce a [mcve] of the issue such that people are able to actually run the code and find the problem.

Comment: Thank you. The data is large. I am not sure how to provide a reproducible example. Hence I have provided snippets of data...

Comment: Noone said it would be easy to ask a question here. But if you want help, you need to somehow shrink your problem such that it reproducibly fits into the question. Find out if it is dependent on your actual data at all; if it isn't producing an example should be pretty easy. If it is, you need to check how much of that data is actually needed.